# Error opening MDB file on network location with EntityFrameworkCore.jet.oledb 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, jet-ef-provider

I have a project opening up MS Access DBs on a network folder. The project is a .net core 3.1 webapi.
EDIT: I'm using EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.OleDb v3.1 with provider in connection string `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

It very simply updates a list of boards based on new ones

```
public void SyncBoards(List<Board> boards)
{
    _cutriteDbContext.RemoveRange(boards);
    _cutriteDbContext.SaveChanges();
    _cutriteDbContext.AddRange(boards);
    _cutriteDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm getting the error (sanitized)

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): The Microsoft Access
> database engine cannot  open or write to the file
> '\{SHAREDFOLDER}{PATH_TO_FILE}\imatv11.mdb'. It is already opened
> exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write
> its data.

This works fine in IIS Express when debugging from VS 2019. I believe this is because the API doesn't have the credentials to access the file. The DBs do not have password protection. Is there a way to provide credentials to the file?

Comment: Does the application have read and write permissions on the network share? Is there an .ldb lock file leftover in the database folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what account is being used under the hood for a web api. Is it always IIS_IUSRS or can it be set to something specific? Can we provide options in the DB config so that the code impersonates a specific account when opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the identity in the IIS application pool in advanced settings.